# delete file from s3 bucket swift

Tags: ios, swift, awss3transferutility, amazon-s3

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64206684/3209705) answer to delete a file from s3 bucket

The task I need to perform is when I'm uploading a new image I need to delete the previous one. So after upload, I'm calling deletion for the previous image. The deletion method gives me success but the file is still there in a bucket. So now, I can see both of the files; the previous one and the new one too. Am I missing something?

Here's my code of upload & delete

```
func uploadfile(image: UIImage, s3Key: String, bucketName: String, completionHandlerWithImageURL: @escaping(_ imageurl: String) -> ())
{
    let transfer_utility = S3TransferUtilityConfig().config()
    let expression = S3Expression().config()
    
    var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
    completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
        debugPrint("Upload Completed")
    }
    
    let bucketName = bucketName
    guard let data = image.pngData() else{
        return
    }

    transfer_utility?.uploadData(data as Data, bucket: bucketName, key: s3Key, contentType: "image/png", expression: expression,
    completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith
    {
        (task) -> AnyObject? in
        if let error = task.error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completionHandlerWithImageURL("")
        }
        
        if let _ = task.result {
            debugPrint("Uploaded image successfully")
            
            if task.result != nil {
                let url = AWSS3.default().configuration.endpoint.url
                let publicURL = url?.appendingPathComponent(bucketName).appendingPathComponent(s3Key)
                if let absoluteString = publicURL?.absoluteString {
                    debugPrint("Image Url :\(absoluteString)")
                    completionHandlerWithImageURL(absoluteString)
                }
            } else {
                debugPrint("Image URL not generated")
                completionHandlerWithImageURL("")
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

func deleteExistingFile(s3Key: String, bucketName: String) {
    let s3 = AWSS3.default()
    guard let deleteObjectRequest = AWSS3DeleteObjectRequest() else { return }
    deleteObjectRequest.bucket = bucketName
    deleteObjectRequest.key = "/images/\(s3Key.components(separatedBy: "/").last ?? "")"
    
    s3.deleteObject(deleteObjectRequest).continueWith { (task:AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Error deleting file on s3 bucket: \(error)")
            return nil
        } else {
            print("s3 file Deleted successfully. \(bucketName) \(s3Key)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I have called both the methods.

```
S3Manager.shared.uploadfile(image: image, s3Key: self.img_key, bucketName: (company_profile["dot"] as? String ?? ""))
    { (imgUrl) in
        if imgUrl != ""
        {
            S3Manager.shared.deleteExistingFile(s3Key: self.profileUrl, bucketName: (company_profile["dot"] as? String ?? ""))
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Uploaded image path:
https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucketNumber/images/img.png

I have tried deleteObjectRequest.key with the full path and only the folder / image path and in both the cases, method gives success but file is still there in a bucket.

deleteObjectRequest.key:
https://bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com/images/old_img.png

deleteObjectRequest.key:
/images/old_img.png

Comment: Do you call delete on completion handler ?

Comment: As i can see you are use to upload images only on main bucket and try to delete in yourMainbucket/images so i think you should have to print upload & delete path. it should be same

Comment: @PtitXav yes in upload file completion handler, I'm calling delete method

Comment: @RakeshPatel I have added upload & delete paths in question. Can you check that? Are they correct?

Comment: @PtitXav I have added the method call code in question. Is it right?

Comment: Are you sure about the profile url as s3key ? You split url with / and get last path component . Debug or log what the entry of s3 delete

Comment: s3 key = https://bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com/images/img.png , deleteObjectRequest.key = /images/img.png does this needs to be a full path? @PtitXav